# True Positive True Negative False Positive False Negative sometimes confusing

Tags: machine-learning

What is the best way to explain True Positive True Negative False Positive False Negative to alleviate confusion?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: You should definitely [edit] to add information about what you're trying to do, what you're using to do it, what you have tried and what the result is.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Please see below picture, I think it's very clear]
Please see below picture, I think it's very clear

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are supposed to be confusing! 
After all, they are attributes of the **[confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Table_of_confusion)**.

Check the **cat ~ no-cat** example used in the Wiki article. I feel it is a pretty adequate and articulate explanation for helping you register these terms in your long-term memory.

Additional read: https://svds.com/the-basics-of-classifier-evaluation-part-1/